# Import dependencies which rely on additional dependencies

Tags: truffle, import

I'm using truffle to create a contract that extends another contract in a GitHub repository e.g.

```
contract Consumer is Chainlinked {

}
```

My first problem is that I an unable to import directly from a Github repository as is suggested here https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_import.html

```
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/solidity/contracts/Chainlink.sol";
```

results in the error

```
Error: Could not find https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/solidity/contracts/Chainlink.sol from any sources; imported from /home/software/ib/oracle/contracts/Consumer.sol
```

So I've copied the file locally. My second problem is that the imported files import a number of other files such as

```
import "solidity-cborutils/contracts/CBOR.sol";
```

These don't resolve locally, so I get an error during compile. Now I could copy all dependencies locally as well, but this seems horribly ineffecient and error prone.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just looked at it for the first time. I think I would be inclined to follow their instructions here: https://docs.chain.link/v1.0/docs/getting-started#section-creating-a-new-chainlinked-project

They show a few ways to do it that will result in local files to import, with the possibility of pulling updates from time to time.

I would incline toward keeping the files local in any case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That works for this particular Chainlink project. In general I assume this is just one of the approaches to contract reuse .

Comment: I'm not too fussy about how the files arrive but I'm in favor of local copies when working with smart contracts. Thanks for accepting my answer.